# how to run command in docker using a script outside thecontainer

Tags: docker, docker-container

in my .mk file I have done as following

```
.PHONY : Test
Test:
  @echo Starting Docker container
  docker container start XXX;
  docker exec -it -w /home/TA/G/T/P XXX bash
  docker exec /home/CO/CO_ANAlysis/bin/c-build --dir results--encoding UTF-8 make
```

and then I want to execute that it execute the first two and when docker container starts the command "docker exec /home/CO/CO_ANAlysis/bin/c-build --dir results--encoding UTF-8 make" doesn't execute

and if I run this out of docker:

```
docker exec -it -w /home/TA/G/T/P SDIO bash /home/CO/CO_ANAlysis/bin/c-build --dir results--encoding UTF-8 make
```

it shows me :

```
/home/CO/CO_ANAlysis/bin/c-build: /home/CO/CO_ANAlysis/bin/c-build: cannot execute binary filehow can I, in a mk file, run commands inside a docker?
```

Thanks

Comment: You'd typically run build commands like this from inside an image's Dockerfile.  If you must use `docker exec` then you can put the actual command you want to run at the end of the `docker exec` line in place of `bash`.

Comment: I corrected my question. when I execute docker exec /home/CO/CO_ANAlysis/bin/c-build --dir results--encoding UTF-8 make nothing happens. it means that script execute the first 2 command and then it's inside the docker and nothing happens, but If i run the command manually in the docker, it works

Comment: The corrected `docker exec` command seems to be missing the container-name argument.  In a script (or a Makefile) you can't "switch to a `docker exec` shell context" and type more commands (this also frequently comes up around remote ssh connections).

Comment: docker exec XXX -it -w /home/TA/G/T/P SDIO bash /home/CO/CO_ANAlysis/bin/c-build --dir results--encoding UTF-8 make doesn't start neither. even if I mention XX which is the container name. would you please correct my code if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved

```
  docker container start XXX;
  docker exec -it -w /home/TA/G/T/P XXX /home/CO/CO_ANAlysis/bin/c-build --dir results--encoding UTF-8 make
```